# Question about filling forms in an editable PDF file

Tags: python, json, ini, pdfrw

As title says I'm trying to fill some PDF fields via Python script, here are the things I used for it:

[My working environment properties]

0 - Operating system : Windows 7 32-bit

1 - **Python version 3.8.3**.

2 - An Editable PDF file, you can get it here **[Editable_PDF.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M7HTkP6fNWNaH_aizfuaA0NdTJhYkgWt/view?usp=sharing)**

3 - Used **pdfrw** library to read and write the PDF file.

4 - Fields names and values from an external configuration file I named **Field_Value.ini**
here it is content

```
R's #=R: 1111
C's #=C: 2222
R's Address=3333
C's Address=4444
Date Filed=5555
Docket #=6666
```

As you see the first column before **=** is some of fields names of that PDF file and the second are values to be filled.

I got them via **pdfforms** utility with this command line

`pdfforms inspect Editable_PDF.pdf`

It will created a **.json** file (named **fields.json**) contains information about each field found in that PDF file.

5 - A Python script to read that **.ini** file and to fill **Editable_PDF.pdf** fields.

Actually I got succeeded in most parts of this, except one small thing which made me ask question about it because honestly I found no solution for it, and I'm still looking.

The thing is that all fields listed in **Field_Value.ini** are filled except this one **Docket #**, no matter I do it just wont be filled, the funny thing is if you try fill it manually via your browser or a PDF editor it is filled. In the start I thought I may putted wrong field name, but no I think it is correct because what ever value I fill I found it convenient name in **fields.json** the same **Docket #**.

So the question here what the hell wrong with that **Docket #** field???, yeah seriously there is something I'm not getting it and I feel it is simple somehow.

I don't want you to write the script for this, I already done one at least for testing. All what you need is to have **pdfrw** library installed with **Python** and this is the script:

```
import pdfrw

PDF_PATH = 'Editable_PDF.pdf'

ANNOT_KEY = '/Annots'
ANNOT_FIELD_KEY = '/T'
ANNOT_VAL_KEY = '/V'
ANNOT_RECT_KEY = '/Rect'
SUBTYPE_KEY = '/Subtype'
WIDGET_SUBTYPE_KEY = '/Widget'

def write_fillable_pdf(input_pdf_path, output_pdf_path, data_dict):
    template_pdf = pdfrw.PdfReader(input_pdf_path)
    annotations = template_pdf.pages[0][ANNOT_KEY]
    for annotation in annotations:
        if annotation[SUBTYPE_KEY] == WIDGET_SUBTYPE_KEY:
            if annotation[ANNOT_FIELD_KEY]:
                key = annotation[ANNOT_FIELD_KEY][1:-1]
                if key in data_dict.keys():
                    annotation.update(
                        pdfrw.PdfDict(V='{}'.format(data_dict[key]))
                    )
    pdfrw.PdfWriter().write(output_pdf_path, template_pdf)

with open("Field_Value.ini", 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
Array = data.split('\n')
for i in range (0, len(Array)): 
    Field_Value = Array[i].split('=')
    Field = Field_Value[0]
    Value = Field_Value[1]
    print (Field , ' = ' , Value)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        data_dict = {
            Field: Value
        }
        write_fillable_pdf(PDF_PATH, PDF_PATH, data_dict)
    
pdf_template = pdfrw.PdfReader(PDF_PATH)
pdf_template.Root.AcroForm.update(pdfrw.PdfDict(NeedAppearances=pdfrw.PdfObject('true')))
pdfrw.PdfWriter().write(PDF_PATH, pdf_template)
```

It might be little ugly but it does what I need.
I thought you guys have an idea about it, so any help appreciated, and thank you even for spending time to just read it.

EDIT:

It seems like **pdfrw** not detecting that field name somehow.

What I did to say that is that I tried to print out detected fields while **pdfrw** processing the PDF file like this `print (key)` or `print (annotation[ANNOT_FIELD_KEY][1:-1])`, it list almost all fields names except the one I'm looking for **Docked #**, so I think that is why it doesn't fill that form.

Anyway I solved this by using another way, I found that **pdftk** can do that via simple command line using a **.fdf** file intead of **.ini**, so yeah at the moment it solved this way.

If you think that the problem with **pdfrw** can be solved would be good.
Any help appreciated.

Smile Regards.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? How did you get the .ini file, is it an output from `pdfforms inspect`?

Comment: I already mentioned "0 - Operating system : Windows 7 32-bit", I use Windows.                  I didn't get that .ini file, I made it using information about the fields I got from the .json file, using this command `pdfforms inspect Editable_PDF.pdf`